# A script in Google spreadsheet works from the script control windows but not from a trigger in the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with this little code I have built for highlighting a word in a Google Sheet.
This code works perfectly when I launch it from the script control windows but it doesn't work when I try to trigger the script from a cell in the sheet.
I'm the owner of this google spreadsheet.
Here is the code :

```
function Surligner(nom) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet() ;
  var mois = sheet.getRange("A4").getValue().getMonth() ;
  var listeNbrJours = new Array(31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31) ;

  // nom = sheet.getRange("M1").getValue() ;

  sheet.getRange(4, 5, listeNbrJours[mois],9).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", null ) ;
  sheet.getRange(4, 5, listeNbrJours[mois],9).setFontColor("black") ;

  for (var i=4 ; i<listeNbrJours[mois]+3 ; i++)
  {
    for (var j=5 ; j<14 ; j++) 
    {
      if (sheet.getRange(i,j).getValue().match(nom) ) 
      { 
        sheet.getRange(i,j).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", null ) ;
        sheet.getRange(i,j).setFontColor("red") ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I trigger the script from the sheet with `=SURLIGNER(M1)` where `M1` is the cell who contain the name to highlight.
The message error is :

> you are not allowed to call the setBorder (line 9)

[image: sheet]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't use a custom function to run `set*` functions

Quoting from 
[Custom Functions in Google Sheets docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

> Spreadsheet    Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).

This means calling the function from sheet won't work.

One possible work around will be to use this

```
nom = sheet.getRange("M1").getValue() ; // I think you thought about it too
```

Then run `Surligner` it using [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) event trigger (although it might create problems due to expensive `Range.getValue` method.